# Calculadora não imprime o valor correto

Tags: c, c++

Olá, estou voltando para a linguagem C depois de um tempo. Sempre usei o Code :: Blocks, mas agora, migrei para o VSCode. Quando tento imprimir valores, saem números gigantescos, como por exemplo: n°1 = 15 e n°2 = 5. Quando vou imprimir, sai um número tipo: 15674213. Desculpem se o texto saiu esquisito. É minha primeira vez aqui!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    //Variaveis
    int num1, num2, soma, subtracao, multiplicacao, divisao;


            soma                   = num1 + num2;
            subtracao              = num1 - num2;
            multiplicacao          = num1 * num2;
            divisao                = num1 / num2;


    //Mensagens
    printf("CALCULADORA 0.1\n");
    printf("A nossa calculadora, realiza calculos com apenas dois números.\n");

    //Coletar primeiro numero
    printf("Digite o primeiro número:");
    scanf("%i", &num1);

    //Coletar segundo numero
    printf("Digite o segundo número:");
    scanf("%i", &num2);

    //Imprimir resultados
    printf("Valor da soma: %i\n", soma);
    printf("Valor da subtração: %i\n", subtracao);
    printf("Valor da multiplicação: %i\n",multiplicacao);
    printf("Valor da divisão: %i\n", divisao);

    //Manter execucao
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Se esta é a ordem dos comandos em seu código então o problema é que você está fazendo as operações **antes** de ler os valores a serem utilizados em tais operações.

Comment: Se está usando o gcc use a opção -Wall, e então mostraria que essas variáveis foram usadas sem serem inicializadas.

Comment: Obrigado! Ajudaram muito aqui!

Answer (score 2):

Você está realizando operações com valores que deveriam vir do teclado, mas ainda não foram lidos. Quando você declara uma variável e a usa sem inicializá-la, o valor que tem nela é desconhecido (conhecido como "lixo de memória"), por essa razão, estava sendo exibidos números grandes. Portanto, para resolver o problema, você deve primeiro ler os valores e, só então, realizar operações com eles, como abaixo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
  //Variaveis
  int num1, num2, soma, subtracao, multiplicacao, divisao;

  //Mensagens
  printf("CALCULADORA 0.1\n");
  printf("A nossa calculadora, realiza calculos com apenas dois números.\n");

  //Coletar primeiro numero
  printf("Digite o primeiro número:");
  scanf("%i", &num1);

  //Coletar segundo numero
  printf("Digite o segundo número:");
  scanf("%i", &num2);


  //realizar as operações (AQUI OS VALORES JÁ FORAM LIDOS, PORTANTO SÃO CONHECIDOS)
  soma                   = num1 + num2;
  subtracao              = num1 - num2;
  multiplicacao          = num1 * num2;
  divisao                = num1 / num2;

  //Imprimir resultados
  printf("Valor da soma: %i\n", soma);
  printf("Valor da subtração: %i\n", subtracao);
  printf("Valor da multiplicação: %i\n",multiplicacao);
  printf("Valor da divisão: %i\n", divisao);

  //Manter execucao
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Além disso, é importante notar que seria mais adequato, salvo caso você queira fazer operacões em diferentes bases, usar o %d ao invés do %i no scanf, porque o %i interpreta valores hexadecimais(0x) e octais(0).

Comment: Obrigado! Me ajudou MUITO!!!

Comment: @Pedro, sim, tem isso também.

Answer (score 0):

Olá,

refiz substituindo o printf/scanf pelo cout/cin, ambas funcionam da mesma forma.

```
#include <iostream>//biblioteca eliminar duplicidades
#include <math.h>//biblioteca operações matemáticas
#include <stdio.h>//biblioteca funções entrada e saída
#include <locale.h>//biblioteca de acentuação

using namespace std;//standard()padrão 

int main()//início
{
//Variáveis
    float n1, n2, soma, subt, divi, multi;

//Mensagens
    cout<<"CALCULADORA 0.1\n";
    cout<<"A nossa calculadora, realiza calculos com apenas dois números.\n";

//Coletar primeiro numero
    cout<<"Digite o primeiro número: ";
        cin>>n1;

//Coletar segundo numero
    cout<<"Digite o segundo número: ";
        cin>>n2;

//Especificando Operações
            soma=(n1+n2);
            subt=(n1-n2);
            divi=(n1/n2);
            multi=(n1*n2);

//Imprimir resultados
    cout<<"\nO resultado da soma de "<<n1<<" + "<<n2<<" é = "<<soma;
    cout<<"\nO resultado da subtração de "<<n1<<" - "<<n2<<" é = "<<subt;
    cout<<"\nO resultado da divisão de "<<n1<<" / por "<<n2<<" é = "<<divi;
    cout<<"\nO resultado da multiplicação de "<<n1<<" multiplicado por "<<n2<<" é = "<<multi;

    return 0;//finaliza e retorna zero//fim algoritmo.`insira o código aqui`
}
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado!